# JMeter generates server error when trying to reproduce an autoComplete tag

Tags: primefaces, jmeter, wildfly

I am trying to load test with JMeter.
I have a program where incidents are created.
For now, when playing the recording, it logs in fine, but when saving data it generates the following error:

*SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-5) Error Rendering View[/alta.xhtml]: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /alta.xhtml @840,111 value="#{alta.**nombre**}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null*

I have noticed that maybe the error is thrown because I have auto-complete lists.
Since, an error that is also seen in the console is:

*SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-5) Error Rendering View[/alta.xhtml]: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeSuggestionsAsList(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:647)*

How can i fix this? Apparently in the JMeter recording all the values ​​are saved...

The autocomplete of the first error that I have put is the following:

```
<p:autoComplete id="via"
            rendered="#{not alta.isNuevoNivel}" 
            dropdown="true"
            widgetVar="viaWV"   
            placeholder="Seleccione la via"                                     
            value="#{alta.nombre}"                                                                                                                          
            requiredMessage="Falta la via"                                          
            completeMethod="#{alta.completeTextPrimeraVia}" 
            required="true" 
            queryDelay="100"
            cache="true"
            forceSelection="true"
            scrollHeight="200"      
            minQueryLength="0"  
            onfocus="if (#{null eq alta.via}) {PF('viaWV').search('');};"
            onclick="PF('viaWV').search('');"
            autoHighlight="false"
            inputStyleClass="comboEditorAutoInput"
            styleClass="comboEditorAuto"
            panelStyleClass="panStyleAuto"                                          
            tabindex="24"   
            disabled="#{alta.isObligada() or not alta.isNueva()}" >
            
            <p:ajax event="itemSelect"  
                    partialSubmit="true"
                    delay="100"                                                 
                    listener="#{alta.onChangeViaEdicion()}" 
                    update="rcCampoViaModificado :formEdicionVia:via_valor"
                    oncomplete="rcCampoViaModificado();" 
                    onerror="onError();"/>                                          
            
            <p:ajax event="clear"                                                   
                    immediate="true"
                    delay="100"
                    listener="#{alta.clearVialEdicion()}" 
                    update="rcCampoViaModificado"
                    oncomplete="rcCampoViaModificado();" 
                    onerror="onError();"/>  
                    
</p:autoComplete>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your request fails due to missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter), for modern [Web 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_2.0) applications the chance of successful replaying recorded script is close to zero as the applications heavily rely on dynamic parameters which are used for [client-side state tracking](https://www.synacktiv.com/ressources/JSF_ViewState_InYourFace.pdf) or [security](https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf/tokens)

When you record the actions in browser JMeter saves the values which are actual at the moment, but when you try to replay the script the values are not actual anymore so you need to extract the dynamic parameters from server response (or replicate their generation logic if they cannot be extracted) and substitute hard-coded values with their dynamic counterparts.

One of the possible ways of detecting dynamic values is recording the same scenario one more time and then comparing generated JMeter test plans - all the values which differ are a subject to [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.
The only difference between recordings is this parameter: 'javax.faces.ViewState'. What value should I put on it?